# Installed atom using MacPorts, but it doesn't show up in Launchpad or Applications folder

Tags: terminal, atom-editor, macports

I wanted to install the text editor Atom (https://atom.io) using the terminal like in Linux, so I performed the following steps on my Mac (version 11.1 Big Sur) as per this tutorial to enable me to use the MacPorts command line tool:

https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html

The steps I executed were:

1. Installed Xcode directly from the App Store (It was a large file, 40 mins to download).
2. Installed MacPorts as a traditional download (i.e. not from the terminal or App Store but from a website: https://github.com/macports/macports-base/releases/tag/v2.6.4)

Version: MacPorts-2.6.4_1-11-BigSur.pkg

Here is the direct link to the MacPorts version I installed: https://github.com/macports/macports-base/releases/download/v2.6.4/MacPorts-2.6.4_1-11-BigSur.pkg

Next I got to the fun part of installing Atom directly from the terminal. I did so using the following command:

```
sudo port -fp install atom
```

This installed a pretty long list of dependancies (30-40 items).  The install completed successfully.

In the terminal (zsh terminal), I tested to see if atom was installed by typing:

```
atom --version
```

It comes back with the error:

```
"command not found: atom"
```

I also looked for Atom in Launchpad, Spotlight Search and Applications folder.  It doesn't seem to be there either.

QUESTION: Does anyone see something I'm missing, or any ideas where Atom might have installed to?

Comment: To see what the port installed run `port contents atom` You do not need the -fp in the install - that might suppress errors so try again without that.

Comment: Indeed, you should almost never use `-f` or `-p` when installing. `-f` means overwrite files that were already there; there shouldn't already be files there so you would want MacPorts to stop with an error if there were. `-p` means proceed if there were errors; you wouldn't want that either; you would want to stop and fix the errors instead. But if the install succeeded, trying again without `-f` and `-p` would do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`port contents` shows you what was installed by a port. For example:

```
port contents atom
```

should reveal to you that it was installed into /Applications/MacPorts/Atom.app.

Applications installed by MacPorts should show up in a Spotlight search and in Launchpad, but it may take a moment after installation before Spotlight has added it to its index. You may need to launch the app manually once (by double-clicking it in the Finder) before it shows up in Launchpad.